# Do I need to use MyFaces if I am using JBoss seam in my application?

Tags: jsf, myfaces, jboss-seam

We have a legacy JSF based web application that uses Seam. It is deployed on Websphere 7.0. It does not have MyFaces JARs in its `/WEB-INF/lib`, it has only Seam JARs.

So, how does the application get the JSF JARs? How does JSF actually work in this application?

Comment: Wepshere 7 has its own classloader and injection provider configured for Servlet 2.5 and a JSF 1.2 implmentation which is bundled within the common libs directory of the app server.  Just adding MyFaces jars to the WEB-INF\lib probably won't work.  Check out this link: http://wasbehindtheglass.blogspot.com/2011/11/myfaces-20-and-websphere-application.html

Comment: @Ivaylo: please stop formatting non-code like library/framework/API names as code. They are not code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF is as being part of Java EE specification already bundled in Java EE compliant application servers like Glassfish, JBoss AS, Websphere and Weblogic. You do not need to bundle it in your webapp.

Your confusion is probably coming, because you've also ever worked with barebones JSP/Servlet containers like Tomcat or Jetty and experienced that you need to manually provide JSF libraries. This is true, barebones JSP/Servlet containers only ships with JSP/Servlet (and EL) libraries, not with other Java EE artifacts like JSF, EJB, JPA, etcetera. That's why you need to bundle it along with your own webapp.

So, to concretely answer your question: no, you do not need to bundle JSF with your webapp if it is already bundled with the target server.

Please note that this is completely regardless of the JSF implementation (you explicitly mentioned MyFaces, while the question/answer applies as good to other JSF implementations like Mojarra).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So just to clarify jboss seam has nothing to do with JSF? So with or w/o jboss seam, application will need JSF jars either in websphere (bundeled) or if some third party implementation then in web app libs?

Comment: Seam is not part of Java EE. It is just an extension to JSF, so it indeed requires JSF. But you don't need to supply JSF libs yourself if the server already provides it.

Comment: EAR of the legacy application we have doesn't have any JSF jars in app itself (it has jsf-facelets.jar though). It also has some seam jars. It means its using jsf bundled with the websphere.

Comment: Yes, as answered, JSF is already bundled in Java EE compliant application servers. Note that JSF libs do definitely not belong in EAR. If webapp needs to bundle JSF, then they belong in WAR (which in turn can be placed inside an EAR).

Comment: It has JSF jars in the classpath. But the ant script which generates EAR doesn't add those jars in the war (bundled in ear).

Comment: As you mentioned seam is JSF extension. Will it create problem if the application is using seam 1.1 (which i think is based on jsf 1.1) and then the app is deployed on websphere which uses JSF 1.2? Do i need to upgrade seam version so that it matches JSf version?

Comment: Just read Seam documentation for prerequirements. I don't do Seam, so I can't answer this offtopic question from top of head. Just press `Ask Question` on right top to ask the new question :)